# Fetch Data from html form to use it in views.py-Django

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks

I am new to django so bear with me.I am trying to build a simple web app to fetch the current weather.Problem is I am not able to fetch the pincode entered in my HTML form and use it in my views.py file.
As I told u I am new to django so please try to explain it the most simple way.
Thanks.[image]

[image]

Comment: @I have edited the code of views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form has `GET` method, but in view you are trying to fetch data from `POST`.
Change view code to this:

```
data=request.GET.get('Location')
```

Also you shoul move

```
return HttpResponse('hello')
```

at the end of view. Code after `return` will never be called.

Comment: sorry,I Posted the unedited version of views.py.I have already tried "data=request.GET.get('Location')"..It doesn't work

Comment: @mathers25 oh I missed `return` statement in you code. Try to move it at the end of function.

Comment: Thanks man!It worked.One more thing..if i want to pass this value to a url to make an api call should i do that in views.py ?

Comment: @mathers25 you are welcome! Sure you can pass in in view as url argument using reverse fuction: `reverse('url', args=[data])` or you can add it to the url as GET arguments: `{0}?data={1}'.format(reverse('url'), data). You can find details about reverse function here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `GET` in form

in views

```
location = request.GET.get('Location')
print(location)
return HttpResponse('whatever')
```